# How to perform javascript if url has anchor

Tags: javascript, anchor

Similar to SO, I want to have an anchor for some comment and after the page is loaded I want the page to do some javascript (highlight,scrolling, etc - that I can write myself)

So If my url is

```
www.mywebapp.com/mypost#45625
```

I'd like the javascript to scroll to div with id `45625` and do my own javascript there.

**How can I write the condition for which to start the execution of my javascript so it would work only if an achor exists?**

Comment: This is done automatically. Try it out.

Comment: @Blender, _"and do some stuff there."_

Comment: Use `id="45625"` rather than `id="#45625"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('#') > -1)
    // Do something.
```

Or even better:

```
if (window.location.hash.length)
    ...
```